# How to find hidden input value with name python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am able to get element with a typical data:
How do I retrieve value with hidden input , an example is this:
html

```
<input type="hidden" name="ringcaptcha_session_id" value="f95dd483a7de725fb56570c763a3e3f90f82d1c3">
```

this website
https://ringcaptcha.com/?utm_source=coderwall&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=phone_verification

i want to find the value, if the rest is known.

I tried it by just leaving the id part away and searching it with the name only, like I am used to, but this didn't go well and I didn't find the value.

my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://ringcaptcha.com/?utm_source=coderwall&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=phone_verification"


r=requests.get(url)

src = r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml")

session_id=soup.find_all("input",{"name":"ringcaptcha_session_id"})
print(session_id)
```

Tried another code and it didn't work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

import urllib.request

url =urllib.request.urlopen("https://ringcaptcha.com/?utm_source=coderwall&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=phone_verification")

soup=BeautifulSoup(url,"lxml")

session_id=soup.find_all("input",name_="ringcaptcha_session_id")

print(session_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the HTML downloaded from that site?  That field is not present in the HTML.  My guess is that, when you login, that established a session, and all future pages have the hidden session ID so it can keep trak of you.  It's a way to do a cookie without using cookies.

Have you tried signing in?

Comment: No, I did not register the income, I just searched for the variable in inspect..

`ringcaptcha_session_id`.

Comment: It's not in the HTML without logging in.

Comment: Sir I am not logged in I searched for the variable in inspect.. 
look the pic
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDXMp.png

Comment: Yes, but that was created by Javascript on the fly.  It's not in the HTML, and that's all that `requests` sees.  Do "view source" on that page, and you'll see that it's not present.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a simple find method as described in the [documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find#find)

```
session_id = soup.find("input",{"name": "ringcaptcha_session_id"}).get("value")
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regexp:

```
import re
match = re.search(r'<input type="hidden" name="ringcaptcha_session_id" value="(.+?)">', src, re.I|re.S )
value = match[1] if match else ''
```